# Determination of directional deformation of deformed and shifted 2D object (triangle)

Tags: geometry

I have an engineering problem. Let's assume there is a 2D structure that undergoes deformation. None of the points stay in initial location and the structure (imagining a triangle should suffice) can undergo translation and rotation. How to calculate local deformation. That is, the true deformation in certain direction. I face the problem that if a triangle rotates and deforms, then I cannot simply subtract their total displacement, in Z direction let's say, in order to get directional deformation (relative displacement between points A and B in Z direction).
I somehow feel that I need at least 3 points of that object in order to determine global rotation and translation and only after that I would be able to get relative directional displacement of any 2 points. But I don't know how! Each point deforms differently while all translate and rotate equally but it's not known how.

The first picture shows idealized situation of the geometrical problem. The second picture shows actual data where the isolated points are initial locations of the geometry and the groups of nodes with similar color of the isolated points are the deformed (translated, rotated) ones. The reason why there's a bunch of them is because it is not actual planar situation but the structure is long in direction Z (assuming screen is XY) and at each Z the initial points deform slightly differently.

Can't post pictures, but see: 
Idealization: https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Ak6M.png 
Actual data: https://i.stack.imgur.com/mmF2Y.png

Update: One method that could work with assumption of small angle changes is that for deformation of any two points I get distance and then distance after deformation. From that I get real relative deformation and I can only distribute that into directional components. Would that suffice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, This is not the cleanest way of doing it, but I it will work.

So, we have a triangle $\{A^0,B^0,C^0\}$ that will deform into $\{A^1,B^1,C^1\}$.

We can ignore the translation and rotation effects by aligning both triangles in the same origin, using their $A$ point, so $A^0=A^1=(0,0)$. By using side $\overline{AB}$, we get the direction of the $x$ axis. The $y$ axis will be simply the perpendicular to $x$.

Then, we can think of a Matrix $D$ that will deform points $B^0$ and $C^0$ into their final positions $B^1$ and $C^1$.

By taking $P^i = (x_P^i,y_P^i)$ for any point $P$ in position $i$, we can construct the equation system:
$$
\left[
\begin{matrix}
\alpha & \beta\\
\gamma & \delta
\end{matrix}
\right]
\left[
\begin{matrix}
x_P^0\\
y_P^0\\
\end{matrix}
\right]
=
\left[
\begin{matrix}
x_P^1\\
y_P^1\\
\end{matrix}
\right]
$$
We can build this system for $B$ and $C$. To ease our lives, we have some constraints to our problem, such that $y_B^0=y_B^1=0$, giving us $\gamma=0$.

$\alpha$ and $\delta$ can be obtained by:
$$
\begin{matrix}
\alpha x_B^0+\beta y_B^0=x_B^1 \Leftrightarrow \alpha=x_B^1/x_B^0\\
\gamma x_C^0+\delta y_C^0=y_ C^1 \Leftrightarrow \delta=y_C^1/y_C^0\\
\end{matrix}
$$

$\beta$ is more tricky, but we will get there:
$$
\alpha x_C^0 + \beta y_C^0 = x_C^1 \Leftrightarrow \beta = 1/y_C^0 \; (x_C^1 - x_C^0.x_B^1/x_B^0)
$$

Now that we have constructed the  $D$ matrix, it think is only a matter of getting the eigenvectors of the matrix, to obtain the principal deformation vectors, and the eigenvalues to give the relative deformation on the respective axis.

Comment: Thanks Diamantino. Eventually simpler solution, that I realized after reading your answer, worked for me. Since for me the problem was mostly deformation of object measured at two points, I approached the problem as a line that changes location and angle. So when you mentioned alignment of one of the points to clear out the angle change,  I realized it sufficed for me to simply measure change of distance of the two points, instead of my initial approach of trying to come to conclusion from absolute displacements of the points.

Comment: All right then. I'm glad that my answer gave you a new insight on the problem.
Cheers